# hive enable describe statement on restricted tables

Tags: hadoop, hive, permissions, apache-spark-sql, describe

When using a big-data tool like `HIVE` usually a `select * from mytable` works,
However, for a user which is only allowed to view specific columns the describe table statement and also integration for tools like Tableau are broken as these no longer can view all (or all allowed) columns as `DESCRIBE TABLE` is no longer possible i.e. denied in ranger.

Is there a workaround to re-enable the `DESCRIBE` statement?
Currently, I see that manually creating a masked view.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that **masking the tables in ranger** is sufficient to restrict access, but retain the ability to execute the `DESCRIBE` statement.

Currently, this is a bit tedious as all columns need to be specified manually - probably atlas & tagging would be a more efficient solution.